# logging the email address in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I wanna log the emails which are being sent from a particular method of the ActionMailer. My ActionMailer consists of many methods which sends email for different reasons, but I to log the emails which are being sent from a particular method and save them in the database.

ActionMailer doesnt allow to do the database operations.

I am newbie to rails ENV,

kindly help me out

Comment: ActionMailer doesn't prevent anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need create your own Delivering system. In this Delivery, you can save your email in your Database and deliver by SMTP or something else.

This method is really not a newbie system. You can create your Delivery like the Mail::SMTP (https://github.com/mikel/mail/blob/master/lib/mail/network/delivery_methods/smtp.rb ) class managing the Delivery system by smtp.